# Запуск приложения под другим пользователем без ввода пароля

Tags: c#, windows

Нужно создать приложение где внутри него выбираешь пользователя, а потом от имени его запускаешь приложение. В windows это решается созданием батника с текстом:

```
runas /savecred /user
```

Можно конечно решить проблему постоянным созданием батника и его запуском, но хочется сделать все полностью на c#.

Comment: Зачем плодить одинаковые вопросы? freim уже ответил вам, что то что вы хотите, не имеет смысла.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight вообще то разные вопросы и там идет разбор по повышению прав. И создание сервиса вместо запуска runas плохая идея, вы не находите?

Comment: Плохая идея - наоборот, использование Runas /savecred. Вы упускаете, что она сохраняет пароль глобально, так, что впоследствии пользователь сможет запустить ЛЮБУЮ программу с использованием этого сохраненного пароля (а не только вашу). Это не что иное, как гигантская дыра в безопасности.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Поясню подробнее. Я системный администратор, управляю несколькими десятками географически распределенными точками через разные утилиты (psExec например). На каждой из них свой есть разные пользователи с разными правами у которых разные пароли. Все пароли записаны в текстовый файл, который лежит у меня на рабочем столе. Так что с дырой в безопасности на своем компе я разберусь. Просто мне нужно запускать скрипты без оглядки на ввод пользователя и пароль. Можно все конечно запускать runas. Но я пишу систему для автоматизации скриптов и хочу все сделать на c#.

Comment: Runas - это обычный exe-файл в system32, который в C# можно запустить через Process.Start, если вы о этом спрашиваете. А вообще, psExec позволяет явно указывать имя пользователя и пароль в параметрах командной строки, так что пункт "то что вы хотите, не имеет смысла" остается в силе.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight я же говорю не только про psExec. И да я могу создавать нужный батник с runas и запускать его, но я хочу обойтись без создания батника. Хочется быть перфекционистом). И кстати запуск psExec с паролем это плохая идея. Пароль легко перехватить.

Comment: @polsok Хотите быть перфекционистом - не изобретайте велосипед, есть готовые нормальные инструменты удаленного контроля за сетью рабочих станций.

Answer (score 1):

Батники не делают никакой магии, которая недоступна из C#. Можно сделать так:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("runas.exe","параметры");
```

Если же вас интересует, как обойтись вообще без runas, то смотрите в сторону функции [CreateProcessWithLogon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw), она ее использует.

- **Внимание!** Вызов Runas с параметром /savecred создает угрозу безопасности, так как пароль сохраняется глобально и после этого можно запустить любую программу с этим сохраненным паролем, повторно вызвав Runas с тем же именем пользователя.

> запуск psExec с паролем это плохая идея. Пароль легко перехватить

Запуск psExec с явно переданным паролем абсолютно эквивалентен запуску psExec через Runas. И в том и другом случае для подключения к удаленному компьютеру выполняется аутентификация NTLM/Kerberos, которая передает по сети не сам пароль, а некоторую функцию от него. Если у вас пароли хранятся в текстовом файле, что мешает программой считывать их из нее и подавать на вход чего угодно (хоть runas, хоть psExec)?